# How to create matrix variable and get unsign value in python

Tags: python, matrix, char

I want to make a variable matrix to get value from a picture in python, I have been searching, I got this code in C++:

```
Mat src, dst;

// Load an image
src = imread("book.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

and then I also want to know how to make `unsigned char` in python, in c++ it is like this :

```
dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0.0;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That C++ code uses OpenCV library, for getting the same result (you must first install Numpy and OpenCV Python wrapper) you only need to do:

```
import cv2
src = cv2.imread('book.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
```

This will generate a `numpy.ndarray` called `src` whose values will be unsigned int (i.e they take values in [0,255] interval)

Comment: so, values that i got from this code "src = cv2.imread('book.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)" have been in unsigned int??

Comment: Yes, you can view the array type doing: `print src.dtype`

Comment: thank you for your help. yes, I get uint8, how if I want 32 bit so I can get RGB value?

Comment: You should ask another question about RGB, so it will help other people in the future when they search for it